# Retrieve All Embedded resources not working in Jmeter-Grafana- Influx DB setup

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb

I have created Jmeter-Grafana-Influx Db in AWS as docker. There are 3 containers for running the whole process
Jmeter Docker Image
Influx db Image
Grafana Image

I am trying to do a load test on a web application which does download a lor of embedded resources when requesting for example the home page.
[image: Retrieve all Embedded resouces is checked for the request]

This is working fine when running in my local machine. But when it come to grafana, the embedded resources are not being downloaded with the same JMX file that I am using in local

Please find the execution etrypoint command in docker-compose file below

```
entrypoint: ["jmeter", "-n", "-t", "/tmp/jmeter-volume/{{service_name}}.jmx", "-p", "/tmp/jmeter-volume/{{service_name}}.properties", "-l", "/tmp/jmeter-volume/results_{{service_name}}_{{ '%H:%M:%S' | strftime | regex_replace(':', '_')}}.jtl", "-j", "/tmp/jmeter-volume/results_{{service_name}}_{{ '%H:%M:%S' | strftime | regex_replace(':', '_')}}.log"]
```

**How I Identified:**

Took the average bytes from summary report with and without embedded resources from my local pc.
Checked the summary report from grafana and found that the average bytes is same as that of the without embedded resources execution.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue using

- [latest JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html)
- [InfluxDbBackendListenerClient with very default settings](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)
- JMeter project main page https://jmeter.apache.org/ as the test url

I clearly see that enabling embedded resources results in 10x times increasing of the response size.

[image]

Do you have HTTP Cache Manager in your test plan? If you do, it will explain the things as the [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) provides browser-like behaviour for embedded resources and real browsers don't download images, scripts, styles, etc. each time, normally they do it only once and the resources are being returned from the browser cache on subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Yes @Dmitri I am using cache manager.and when running in local its working fine .As I mentioned I am using cache manager for real time behavior. But here lets consider a single request to home page, the embedded resources should get downloaded. In grafana I see its not running. I am most probably missing something somewhere.

Comment: I tried multiple methods but nothing worked . Hope its something related to the jmeter docker image setup that I have created and hosted. COuld you please suggest me a git URL where I can find a good Jmeter-grafana -Influxdb setup(The one which you are using).